# Issues installing Umbraco on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, umbraco

I am having lots of problems install Umbraco on SQL Server 2008 are there know compatibility issues?

Also are there any good reasons not to use SQL Server CE 4?

Comment: It is very easy install Umbraco with SQL Server 2008 provide more details about issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Umbraco? V5.x will *only* run on SQL 2008 out of the box. Umbraco 4.7 will definitely run just fine on SQL2008.

There is no reason you can't use SQLCE for development, but I wouldn't recommend it.

For production - the performance is just not good enough (though I suppose with a low traffic site it might work). With the much more powerful SQL Express also available for free, there is very little reason not to use it from the get-go, and it would alleviate the SQLCE->SQL Express upgrade headaches you may encounter down the road.